# How do I add a user to the "Authenticate" menu?

Tags: 14.04, unity, sudo, authentication

I am talking about the menu shown in the screenshot provided:

[image]

When I click on "Select user...", a list of users is shown, but my user is missing, although I have sudoer permissions.

Comment: How did you grant your user `sudo` permissions? By adding to the `sudo` group?

Comment: Executing `sudo adduser username sudo` solved my problem, I assumed having sudo permissions is equivalent to being in the sudo group. Guess i was wrong

Comment: @muru I didn't set up my user account myself, so I don't know how this user was granted sudo permissions